# Error message in cmd stating that name does not exist or that there is nothing internal or external related to this

Tags: cmd

stating that name does not exist or that there is nothing internal or external related to this. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I downloaded files for school and created a folder on the desktop and need to change the drive in cmd, but can't.
can someone please help me with this?

Comment: We can't tell you, what's wrong with your code, when you don't share it..

Comment: thanks for your ignorant response I will try to develop the telepathic capabilities to amuse you not.

Comment: well, your errormessage tries to tell you something like "There is no such command". We can't tell you, what's wrong with your command, when we don't see it. How is that ignorant?

Answer (score 0):

> need to change the drive in cmd

I do not understand the rest of your question, but if you are trying to change drives in Windows CMD, there are two ways. For example to go to your `D:` drive:

1. `D:`
2. `cd /D "D:\"`

or for a specific folder on another drive:

3. `cd /D "D:\Example\Folder Name\Subfolder"`